# Tail bounds for i.i.d. sums with Poisson number of terms

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose $N, X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent Poisson($\lambda$) variables. I am interested in exponentially small tail bounds for $S := \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ for large $\lambda$. I would like to know if there are results which would imply the asymptotics of
$$
-\log \mathbf{P}(S \ge k), \quad \lambda \to \infty
$$
when $k/\mathbf{E}S = k/\lambda^2 \to \infty$.

I have analyzed the point probabilities of $S$ using Stirling's formula and this seems to give a curious transition
$$
     - \log \mathbf{P}(S \ge k) \sim
      \begin{cases}
        k \ln \frac{\ln \frac{k}{\lambda}}{\lambda}, & \quad \text{if } \lambda \ll \ln \frac{k}{\lambda} \\
        k \ln(1 + c) & \quad \text{if } \ln(k/\lambda) \sim c \lambda \\
        \frac{k}{\lambda} \ln \frac{k}{\lambda^2}, & \quad \text{if } \lambda \gg \ln \frac{k}{\lambda}
      \end{cases}
$$
More generally, I would like to "compound" such distributions an arbitrary number of times, i.e., I'm interested in tails of $S' = \sum_{i=1}^S X'_i$, where $X'_i$ are i.i.d. Poisson($\lambda$), of $S'' = \sum_{i=1}^{S'} X''_i$, where $X''_i$ are i.i.d. Poisson($\lambda$), and so forth.

Note that this is also a question about the upper tail of the size of the fixed level in a Galton--Watson tree with Poisson($\lambda$) offspring distribution. I wonder if there are results concerning concentration of such random tree functionals.

Comment: The probability of getting $n$ is  $ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (m\lambda)^n  \lambda^m e^{ - (m+1) \lambda} / (n ! m!)  = ( \lambda^n e^{-\lambda} / n!) \sum_{r=1}^n \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n}{r}  (\lambda e^{-\lambda})^r  $ so maybe asymptotics for Stirling numbers of the second kind will help?